# Is it possible to make part of a Firebase real-time database structure, local only

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Real-time database with a many-to-many structure similar to the following:

```
App {
   "users" : {
        "user123" : {
            "name" : "Mr Guy"
            ...
            "groups" : {
                "group567" : true,
                "group890" : true
            }
        }
    }
    "groups" : {
        "group567" : {
            "name" : "My Group 1",
            "other" : "some other random stuff",
            "logs" : {
                 "guid345" : {
                     "author" : "Miss Other",
                     "note" : "some change note"
                 },
                 "guid817" : { ... },
                 "guid018" : { ... },
                 ...
             },
             "members" : {
                 "user123" : true,
                 ...    
             }
        }
    }
}
```

These are mapped to some objects:

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private List<Groups> groups;
}

class Group {
    private String name;
    private Other other;
    private List<Log> logs;
}

class Log {
    private String author;
    private String note;
}
```

I'm now at the point that I want to optimise how much data is downloaded. (The logs node of each Group do not matter to the user, except for items added while the user is active - this means it is expected each user will see a different list of logs.)

I know how ignore the logs field and not send it to Firebase - I have an implementation where I save the logs separately in sqlite, but rather than do this manually **is there a way to set a property to save in the local copy of the Firebase Database but not sync that part to Remote?** so that I can avoid a separate datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal for Firebase real-time database or for the new Cloud Firestore database is to work in real-time and not to work as offline databases. Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.

When you enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to the device so your app can maintain state while offline. You can enable disk persistence using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

If you want to be compltely offilne you can use FirebaseDatabase's [goOffline()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()) method:

> This method shuts down our connection to the Firebase Database backend until goOnline() is called.

However, I don't recommend you to use Firebase real-time database as an offline-only database. It is really designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. If you want to use an offline-only database, you can use as also @Doug Stevenson mentioned mentioned in his answer, the [Room Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room):

> The Room persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Realtime Database has no sense of "local only" data.  Everything is synchronized at the earliest opportunity.

If you want a local relational database, consider looking into [Android Jetpack's Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) - it provides exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I need realtime synchronisation between users, which isn't built into room. Firebase can work offline when there is no internet, I'm just hoping there is a way to manipulate that

Comment: There is not.  As I said, it will synchronize everything at the earliest opportunity.  Realtime Database "works" while offline, but it's not meant for ongoing offline use.  There are distinct limitations when working offline.